# How do I detect changes in my node_modules including deleting files when using msbuild incrementally

Tags: msbuild, fivem

I'm working on a script for FiveM. The core code is C# and the NUI is built on VUE.js. The inside of the project dir we have the following structure

ProjectDir/

- Main.cs
- fxmanifest.lua
- Other .cs files
- ui/

  - package.json
  - node_modules/ <-- node stuff
  - src <-- contains .vue, .html, and .js files

I've created this .targets file that I want to just run after the standard cs project build

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Name>NUI_TARGETS</Name>
        <NUISourceDir>$(ProjectDir)ui\</NUISourceDir>
        <NUITargetDir>$(TargetDir)ui\</NUITargetDir>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <NUISrcFiles Include="$(NUISourceDir)**\*.vue;$(NUISourceDir)**\*.js;$(NUISourceDir)**\*.html" />
        <NUISourceNodeModules Include="$(NUISourceDir)node_modules\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="NUIInstall" AfterTargets="Build" Inputs="@(NUISourceNodeModules);$(NUISourceDir)package.json" Outputs="$(NUISourceDir)node_modules\.install-stamp">
        <Message Text="Installing NUI JS Dependencies" Importance="high" />
        <Exec Command="npm install" WorkingDirectory="$(NUISourceDir)"/>
        <!-- write the stamp so we can check if we need to reinstall -->
        <Touch Files="$(NUISourceDir)node_modules\.install-stamp" AlwaysCreate="true"/>
    </Target>
    <Target Name="NUIBuild" AfterTargets="NUIInstall" Inputs="@(NUISrcFiles)" Outputs="$(NUISourceDir)dist\index.html">
        <Message Text="Clearing NUI distribution directories" Importance="high" />
        <RemoveDir Directories="$(NUISourceDir)dist;$(NUITargetDir)dist"/>
        <Message Text="Building NUI" Importance="high" />
        <Exec Command="npm run build" WorkingDirectory="$(NUISourceDir)" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="NUICopyPOSIX" AfterTargets="NUIBuild" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'" Inputs="$(NUISourceDir)dist\index.html" Outputs="$(NUITargetDir)dist\index.html">
        <Message Text="Copying NUI to $(NUITargetDir)dist on POSIX" Importance="high" />
        <Exec Command="XCOPY &quot;$(NUISourceDir)dist\&quot; &quot;$(NUITargetDir)dist\&quot; /S /Y"/>
    </Target>
    <Target Name="NUICopyUNIX" AfterTargets="NUIBuild" Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'" Inputs="$(NUISourceDir)dist\index.html" Outputs="$(NUITargetDir)dist\index.html">
        <Message Text="Copying NUI to $(NUITargetDir)dist on UNIX" Importance="high" />
        <Exec Command="mkdir -p &quot;$(NUITargetDir)dist\&quot;"/>
        <Exec Command="mv &quot;$(NUISourceDir)dist\&quot; &quot;$(NUITargetDir)&quot;" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I what I would like the flow to be:

1. After the build finishes (regardless of whether there are any cs changes) run NUIInstall if and only if either the package.json changes or if any of the node_modules are modified or removed
2. After NUIInstall, run NUIBuild if and only if any of the .js, .vue, or .html files have been changed in the ui\src folder
3. After NUIBuild and only if NUIBuild actually ran run either NUICopyUNIX or NUICopyPOSIX based on the current os.

Currently this seems to successfully actually run and give me the desired output. However, it doesn't correctly detect changes, especially deleted files, and skip the unnecessary steps. What do I have to change to get this to work?

**If at all possible I would like to avoid any MSBuild extensions.**